# Android Calendar View. Months displayed continuously

Tags: android, android-calendar, calendarview

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmFZX.png) I'm trying to use CalendarView in my app. All the months are displayed continuously. Can some one help me how to display only the current month and also choose different months?

```
<CalendarView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
```

Comment: what does it means " month are displayed continuously"?

Comment: I've added a screenshot in my question. Kindly look into that link

Comment: @fredrickcyril [check](https://github.com/gongmingqm10/awesome-calendar) this.

Comment: show your full xml please

Comment: The same issue happend to me in while testing in API 22 (lollipop). However it worked fine with marshmallow.

Answer (score 2):

I found that it's caused by the height of the `CalendarView`, if you set it this way `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` your calendar will show the months until there is available space.

Try setting a height like 200dp or put it in a Linear/Relative layout with a height.

**Update**

```
<CalendarView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

[image]

```
<CalendarView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="200dp" />
```

[image]

This is the difference between using `wrap_content` or `200dp` as height.

Alternatively, you can set min and max Date for the same month, and, if you need, you can change the min/max programmatically.

```
<CalendarView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:minDate="11/01/2016"
       android:maxDate="11/30/2016"/>
```

Note: this 2 workaround are for Android L, from M you don't need this.

Comment: Sorry but  this question is not yours, why do you say this not work? I try this and work for me

Comment: I too face this issue and tried your solution. It didn't work

Comment: It works for me, have you also tried with the min/max ?

Answer (score 2):

Set minimum and maximum date for calender view so the only the current month is displayed.

```
Calendar currentCalendarView = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calendar = currentCalendarView;
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,currentCalendarView.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
calendarView.setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, currentCalendarView.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
calendarView.setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```